# Matching a transient/detached entity against a Spring Data JPA Criteria Specification

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Spring Data JPA's JpaSpecificationExecutor exposes methods to retrieve, delete, or check for existence (in the database) of entities matching a given criteria `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification`.

Assuming I need to match a transient/detached entity object (i.e. one that has yet to be persisted to/has been deleted from the database) against a Specification (or Predicate) as it's being used for e.g. `findAll(Specification<T>)`; how would a go about doing so?